# Detect type of non printing character in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

In word vba, I need to select entire line, and to be able to know which kind of non printing character it is (page break, section break, ... )

[image: Different non printing characters]

After various attempts not worth sharing, I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the text you want to check and run this, it will print the ASCII value for each character in the selected text. You can use this value to see what character it is.

```
Sub MM()
    For i = 1 To Selection.Characters.Count
       Debug.Print Selection.Characters(i) & ":" & vbTab & Asc(Selection.Characters(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi.Even though it's a little bit late, thank you very much for the answer. It works great